# Normality test in R

Tags: r, normalization

I want to test normality in R, my data looks like:

[image: Each column represents different transcripts (t1,t2,t3....) and each row represents patient ids (p1,p2,p3)]

I want to do normality test for each of the transcript. I used the code as:

```
my_data <- read.csv("b.csv")
my_data
shapiro.test(my_data$t1)
```

When I am doing `shapiro.test(my_data)`

```
Error: is.numeric(x) is not TRUE
```

It gave me result for `t1`, likewise I want to do for all, how to do it at once?

Comment: Can you upload your CSV file somewhere instead of just showing an image?

Comment: Ya sure, but I am not getting option to attach csv file, only images file option is there

Answer (score 0):

Create a list for column names
Something like this can work

```
data <- data = c(my_data["t1"], my_data["t2"],...)
```

And then use the shapiro wilk test accordingly

```
shapiro.test(data)
```